# Auto-Indenting \if statements with AUCTeX

Tags: latex, auctex, indentation, tex

The current `AUCTeX` behaviour for primitive `tex` code involving *if*-like statements is to indent the conditional statement at the same level as the surrounding condition. I.e. code such as

```
\if@sometoggle%
\dosomething%
\else%
\doanotherthing%
\fi%
```

appears as a big block of text. I would like to make `AUCTeX` indent the snippet as follows:

```
\if@sometoggle%
  \dosomething%
\else%
  \doanotherthing%
\fi%
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible:

```
(setq LaTeX-begin-regexp "\\(?:begin\\|if@\\)\\b")
(setq LaTeX-end-regexp "\\(?:end\\|else\\|fi\\)\\b")
(defun LaTeX-indent-level-count ()
  "Count indentation change caused by all \\left, \\right, \\begin, and
\\end commands in the current line."
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (let ((count 0))
        (narrow-to-region (point)
                          (save-excursion
                            (re-search-forward
                             (concat "[^" TeX-esc "]"
                                     "\\(" LaTeX-indent-comment-start-regexp
                                     "\\)\\|\n\\|\\'"))
                            (backward-char)
                            (point)))
        (while (search-forward TeX-esc nil t)
          (cond
            ((looking-at "left\\b")
             (setq count (+ count LaTeX-left-right-indent-level)))
            ((looking-at "right\\b")
             (setq count (- count LaTeX-left-right-indent-level)))
            ((looking-at LaTeX-begin-regexp)
             (setq count (+ count LaTeX-indent-level)))
            ((looking-at "else\\b"))
            ((looking-at LaTeX-end-regexp)
             (setq count (- count LaTeX-indent-level)))
            ((looking-at (regexp-quote TeX-esc))
             (forward-char 1))))
        count))))
```

Note that I had to re-define `LaTeX-indent-level-count`.
The diff is simply one `cond` branch:

```
((looking-at "else\\b"))
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Having the same problem as the OP, I copied your code and it worked, but not fully satisfactory.  It indents only till the next `\else`.  The position of the `\else` is correct, but the following code (`\doanotherthin`, see question) is still in the first column, instead of column 3.  I changed your first code line, to incorporate also the \ifx-command and thought, adding the else command would help, but I failed (at least with again indenting after `\else`).  So here is my partially working code: `(setq LaTeX-begin-regexp "\\(?:begin\\|if\\|ifx\\|else\\)\\b")`  Any ideas?