# Indenting LaTeX code for \if \else \fi statements

Tags: latex, auctex, indentation, tex

This is related to [this Emacs.SE question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5439/auto-indenting-if-statements-with-auctex/5493#5493).

I use the code from the answer:

```lisp
(setq LaTeX-begin-regexp "\\(?:begin\\|if@\\)\\b")
(setq LaTeX-end-regexp "\\(?:end\\|else\\|fi\\)\\b")
(defun LaTeX-indent-level-count ()
  "Count indentation change caused by all \\left, \\right, \\begin, and
\\end commands in the current line."
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (let ((count 0))
        (narrow-to-region (point)
                          (save-excursion
                            (re-search-forward
                             (concat "[^" TeX-esc "]"
                                     "\\(" LaTeX-indent-comment-start-regexp
                                     "\\)\\|\n\\|\\'"))
                            (backward-char)
                            (point)))
        (while (search-forward TeX-esc nil t)
          (cond
            ((looking-at "left\\b")
             (setq count (+ count LaTeX-left-right-indent-level)))
            ((looking-at "right\\b")
             (setq count (- count LaTeX-left-right-indent-level)))
            ((looking-at LaTeX-begin-regexp)
             (setq count (+ count LaTeX-indent-level)))
            ((looking-at "else\\b"))
            ((looking-at LaTeX-end-regexp)
             (setq count (- count LaTeX-indent-level)))
            ((looking-at (regexp-quote TeX-esc))
             (forward-char 1))))
        count))))
```

But instead of getting this indentation:

```latex
\ifx\condition
  \dosomething
\else
  \dosomethingelse
\fi
```

I do get

```latex
\ifx\condition
  \dosomething
  \else
  \dosomethingelse
\fi
```

Hoe to get the `\else` in line with `\if` and `\fi`?

Comment: The `LaTeX-begin-regexp` seems to take into account two alternatives: `begin` and `if@`. What happens If you add the third alternative to the expression, such as `"\\(?:begin\\|if@\\|ifx\\)\\b`?